# BASIC_TPU is not a valid choice in ML Engine

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-ml

I've been following [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/using-tpus) to using TPUs in ML Engine but get an error that BASIC_TPU is an invalid choice:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.ml-engine.jobs.submit.training) argument --scale-tier: Invalid choice: 'BASIC_TPU'.

Valid choices are [BASIC, BASIC_GPU, CUSTOM, PREMIUM_1, STANDARD_1].
```

According to the doc, this should be a valid choice. Has anyone else run into this? Is this just the result of TPUs being in beta?

Comment: did you try `gcloud beta ml-engine ...`?

Comment: This wasn't really the solution, but, because I couldn't use the beta component, I realized I had a really old version of google-cloud-sdk. Now that I've updated, everything seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please run `gcloud version` to check the version of Google Cloud SDK installed in your environment? `BASIC_TPU` was introduced in version [180.0.0](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#18000_2017-11-15)